# In Sublime Text 3, What is the scope of the "GoTo Anything" Panel?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I'm interested in the `scope` of the "GoTo Anything" Panel.

I tried to use `Scope Hunter` and `ScopeAlways`
but both of them seem to be disabled when the Panel is Active.

[image]

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? the scope will be `text.plain` because the Goto Anything widget textbox does not have a syntax assigned by default

Comment: I realized that it's possible to call snippets inside the panel when the snippet has no scope. It is useful for filtering files only inside a specific path.
The down side of not defining scope on a snippet is that it available everywhere.

Comment: Hmm.. `text.plain` is not working unfortunately.

Comment: if you type something in that box i.e. `abc` and then from the `Tools` menu -> Developer -> Show Scope Name, you'll see that it is indeed `text.plain`.

Answer (score 0):

The scope `text.plain`...

You can know the scope your cursor's on by pressing `ctrl+shift+alt+p` on windows. (`Tools -> developer -> show scope`).